# What is Windows Metro style app

Tags: microsoft-metro

Could anybody in simple term explain what is Windows Metro style app? What is the purpose and what kind of application we can make using this?

Any link for beginners will be of great use..

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the new Windows8 Metro interface just a UI redesign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519853/is-the-new-windows8-metro-interface-just-a-ui-redesign)

Comment: no, that question has a different context to it- this is more how to develop for it/is it even useful.

Comment: See this Windows 8 preview - http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/features/2011/jun11/06-01corporatenews.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Metro style apps are full screen apps tailored to your users' needs, tailored to the device they run on, tailored for touch interaction, and tailored to the Windows user interface. Windows helps you interact with your users, and your users interact with your app." from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/windows/apps/hh464920).

All about developing for Windows 8: 
http://www.buildwindows.com/

When developing Metro apps you can chose from a variety of languages and technologies:

- HTML + JS + CSS
- XAML + (C# or VB)
- XAML + (C++ or C)

Answer (score 8):

A Metro style app is an app built using HTML5 or XAML+(C#,VB or C++), on Microsoft's new APIs - in short, it's a an app-widget-kinda-thing. Note that this is cross-platform compatible (Windows 8 will support ARM with metro apps) and that standard x86 apps built the "old way" will still continue to work, but are not considered metro apps, nor are they cross-platform compatible. There is also an app store for metro apps.

Due to the lack of system APIs, these apps are fairly limited - think iOS style apps, where it's sandboxed. Metro apps also make use of the cloud more than ever for data storage, and are required to stay open (user should not quit a metro app) unless rebooted or via task manager.

Links: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/BPS-1004

Comment: The Windows 8 Developer Preview has been released and some preliminary API documentation is available. You can start trying your hand at developing Metro apps already.

Comment: Yes, my bad- I just realized I was off by the dates; i WAS once a Windows developer, now Mac, so forgive me :]

Comment: Metro has nothing to do with HTML5.

Comment: Metro uses HTML5 as its language, Metro in itself is just a new API + UI design.

Answer (score 3):

Metro style application redesigns the Windows user interface (more focus on clean typography and less on UI chrome),have a  full screen UI, introduced   Flat colored  “live tiles”(update user about the application and draw them into application) ,heaving touch-centric style, designed for multitasking(Snapped view, Filled view),can be packaged up and distributed via  the “Windows Application store ” and can be deployed in multiple locals and languages.

Answer (score 0):

Metro apps are touch-screen-friendly apps written especially for Microsoft's WinRT programming interfaces.

ARM-based Windows RT devices, such as the Surface tablet, will only be able to run Metro apps. Devices running Windows 8 will be able to run both Metro apps and Win32 apps.

Metro apps will be available for distribution on the Windows Store.